# Recursive object deletion

Tags: java, recursion, null

I'm having difficulty making a method that recursively removes all references to objects with a class like:

```
class CoolObject
{
    int someData;
    CoolObject[] subObjects; // array and each element get initialized elsewhere

    void nullSubObjects()
    {
        if(subObjects != null)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < subObjects.length; o++) 
            {  
                if (subObject[o] != null)
                {
                  subObject[o].nullSubObjects(); //returns exception here
                  subObject[o] = null;
                } 
            } 
            subObjects = null; 
        }
    }
}

Class elsewhere
{

    void update(CoolObject currentObject)
    {
        //test for creation
        if(currentObject.subObject == null && and other conditions)
        {
            currentObject.subObject = new CoolObject[52];

            for(int m = 0; m < 52; m++) 
                 currentObject.subObject[m] = new CoolObject();         
        }

        //test for deletion
        if(currentObject.subObject != null && and other conditions)
             currentObject.nullSubObjects();



        //recursive update
        if(currentObject.subObjects != null)
             for (int q = 0; q < 52; q++) update(currentObject);
     }
}
```

Whenever I go to update the structure it results in a null pointer exception inside the loop, despite having just checked to make sure the subObject was not null...

**Why am I getting this exception?**

**Without explicitly nullifying it, will the 'someData' prevent their GC?**

---

Thank you all for the feedback!

This implementation was a over complicated means of ensuring subObjects would be more likely to be removed by the automatic GC. I've settled on nullifying the subObjects array at higher levels, and calling System.gc()

Without doing so, my otherwise 40k program would exceed 2Gb before anything was being deleted.

Comment: The way to fix it is to read the stack trace of the NullPointerException to understand where it's thrown, and thus what is null.

Comment: Aside from anything else, that's a really horrible way of formatting the code... *very* unclear.

Comment: Is your question *actually* about whether you need to set everything to null (you almost certainly don't) or why you're getting an exception?

Comment: _array and each element get initialized elsewhere_ Can you provide that code??

Comment: You're clearly showing us made up code instead of showing us the actual code. And you still haven't posted the stack trace of the exception. Voting to close.

Comment: I wish this was real code. This is even missing a particular closing brace of the `for(int o = 0;...` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do any of this to make an object garbage collectable!

An object becomes garbage when it it no longer accessible, i.e. when it has no accessible references.

Take the following example:

```
class A {
    int i;
}

class B {
    A a = new A();
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        // point 1
        b = null;
        // point 2
    }
}
```

At `point 1`, an object of type `B` exists, referred to by `b` and an object of type `A` exists, referred to by `b.a`.

You can imagine a chain of references like this:

```
+ main
| + object of B
  | - object of A
```

At `point 2`, I can no longer access the object of type `B` so it is eligible for garbage collection.  I also have no way to access the object of type `A`, so it will also be garbage collected.

Now the chain of references looks like this:

```
+ main 
| (no references)

+ object of B
| - object of A
```

Even though the object of type `B` has a reference to the object of type `A`, there is still no way to get to that object from `main`.

An object is garbage collected when there is no chain of references to it that can actually be used by the program.

Comment: In the case where i only call subObjects = null; there is a sort of memory leak... and this class is the only place it can be happening.

Comment: @user3537499: no, there is no memory leak.

Comment: @JBNizet: Without frequent calls to System.gc(), the program would go way beyond the expected RAM usage of ~40k to beyond 2Gb before any of the objects would be deleted... Is there another term you would use to describe this?

Comment: @user3537499 JBNizet it right. A memory leak is when the memory is unrecoverable (until say the program exits and the memory is reclaimed by the OS).

Comment: @user3537499: that's not a memory leak. That's the GC deciding not to garbage collect until it's really needed to avoid OutOfMemoryErrors. If you start your JVM with options asking for a much smaller heap size, the GC will collect more often.

Comment: @user3537499 If you experiencing such high memory usage, but know that most of it is taken up by garbage, then you can set the VM's heap memory limit with the `-Xmx<size>`

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting this exception?

I can think of a couple of reasons why you might get a NPE at that point.

- If the network of objects is cyclic, then a `CoolObject` instance can be reached via a recursive `nullSubObjects()` call while it is already being processed.  Since the recursive call nulls the `subObjects` field, when you return from the recursion in the middle of the `for` loop and execute `subObject[o].nullSubObjects();` `subObject` will be `null` and you will get an NPE.
- If some other thread is updating the graph while you are doing this, all bets are off.  This code has no synchronization.

I'd also note that this is not the real code (it is no compilable).  The real problem may be something that only exists on the real code.

---

> Is there a safer way to ensure all references are removed?

This should avoid the first problem:

```
    if (subObjects != null)
    {
        CoolObject[] s = subObjects;
        subObjects = null;
        for (int o = 0; o < s.length; o++) 
        {  
            if (s[o] != null)
            {
              s[o].nullSubObjects(); //returns exception here
              s[o] = null;
            } 
        }
    }
```

However, this is probably unnecessary away; see below.

> Without explicitly nullifying it, will the 'someData' prevent their GC?

The whole tree / graph will be garbage collected once all existing references to it become unreachable.  It is hard to imagine a situation where it *necessary* to null all of the references like this.